# Lanzar un Dialog dentro de la respuesta de un servicio sin que continúe la ejecución

Tags: android, kotlin, async, alert

Recién empiezo en Adroid y por ende en Kotlin. Tengo un problema debido a mi falta de conocimiento. Agradecería sus sugerencias para encontrar la solución.

Hago un post a una api y en la respuesta exitosa quiero mostrar un Dialog, el problema es que no quiero que la ejecución siga sino he dado click para cerrar el dialog. Pero por más que intento el dialog, se muestra y se cierra sin siquiera poder verlo y el código continúa.

Necesito enviar a otra activity hasta que se haya cerrado el Dialog.

**Llamada a post**

```
fun resetPassword(reset: ResetPass, contex: Context, fragmentManager: FragmentManager){
    disposable = retrofit.resetPass(reset)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { res ->
                showDialog(fragmentManager, contex)

            }, { error ->
                Constantes.showMessage(contex, error.message!!)
            Log.e("TAG:", "Error ${error}")}
        )
}
```

**Función de llamada a Dialog**

```
private fun showDialog(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, contex: Context) {
    var dialog = Dialogos()

    dialog.show(fragmentManager, "Alert")

    contex.startActivity(Intent(contex, LoginActivity::class.java))
}
```

**Clase donde creo el Dialog**

```
class Dialogos: DialogFragment() {

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return activity?.let {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
        builder
            .setTitle(R.string.titleDialog)
            .setMessage(R.string.messageDialog)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                    dialog.cancel()
                })

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        builder.create()
    } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Actividad no puede ser nula")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eso pasa porque estás iniciando `LoginActivity` en el método `showDialog`

El cambio es sencillo en el listener de positive button puedes agregar la instrucción para iniciar la activity de la siguiente manera.

```
.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                dialog.cancel()
                startActivity(Intent(requireContext(), LoginActivity::class.java))
            })
```

Y tu método show dialog quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
   private fun showDialog(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, contex: Context) {
    val dialog = Dialogos()
    dialog.show(fragmentManager, "Alert")
}
```

De esta manera funciona, sin embargo, como podrás ver tu dialogo esta fuertemente acoplado a tu activity, yo te recomendaría utilizar la comunicación entre tu dialogo y activity por medio de un listener y de esta manera tu dialogo estará desacoplado y lo podrás utilizar en otras activities.

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que hice y me funciona bien, sin embargo, por no tener mucha experiencia aún desconozco algunos términos, entonces no sé cómo implementar eso que me dices. De hecho sé que estoy mal porque ese Dialog no lo podría reutilizar, pero no sé cómo desacoplarlo. Tienes algún enlace donde pueda documentarme por favor?